# guards on selectors from Less to Sass

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm  switching over from Less to Sass and am wondering how I do the following?

In Less I can add a guard to a rule-set so that it only compiles if I have set the has-badge variable to enabled (it's not a mixin being called from elsewhere but a self contained block).

```
.badge when (@has-badge = enabled){
    display: inline-block; border-radius: $badge-radius; padding: $badge-padding; min-width: 1em; text-align: center; font-size: $badge-font-size; line-height: 1em;
}

@has-badge: enabled;
```

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service, have you tried anything, anything at all?

Comment: I did actually but Sass and Less use quite different terminology.

Comment: Where did you try something?  Because it just looks like you posted LESS code in hopes that someone will do the work of converting it for you.  The Sass documentation is literally a single page long.  If you understand what a guard is in LESS, you should have had absolutely no trouble figuring out what constructs in Sass are comparable *if you had read the documentation*.

Comment: You could say the same thing about a lot of questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the ability to use simply if/else statements in SASS and compare a string to a value like in the following example:

```
.badge {
    @if $has-badge == "enabled" {
        display: inline-block; border-radius: $badge-radius; padding: $badge-padding; min-width: 1em; text-align: center; font-size: $badge-font-size; line-height: 1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lovely thanks. I now have about a hundred to convert by hand. Oh well.